# Deactivate menu item in Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I am using a `DialogFragment` to display a list of menu items in the dialog by setting the items based on a string array.

```
public class MenuDialogFragment extends 

    private Menu mMenu;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
                .setItems(R.array.menu_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                            // ...
                        }
                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }
```

What do I need to do, to deactivate (disable) one of the menu item entries? How can I get hold of them? Didn't find the right method in [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Comment: try `menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(false);`

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal In which method?

Comment: Disable it where ever you require it in your code, if you want it to be disabled when you show the `AlertDialog` you can put it before you show the `AlertDialog`

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal no, I mean in which method would I get hold of the `Menu` reference, I don't have in present.

Comment: i have posted the code in the answer with `menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {
    private Menu menu;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        // Create your menu...
        this.menu = menu;
        return true;
    }
    ....
}
```

Then use the following code whenever you want to disable the menu item:

```
menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Yeah, but when is menu not null? ;-) when I am using the builder it's still null.

Comment: can you post the code of when you are building your menu ?

Comment: I've added more code to give you a better idea about the whole DialogFragment, create dialog, set items, show problem. I know how to deactivate menu items in general.

Comment: try using `alertDialog.getListView();` like in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12946119/3326331)

Comment: This looks promising, but again it's available in onClick, that's too late.

Comment: yes you can move the `onClick()` code out of the block, move some edits to the code and then put the code just before you call `show()` on the dialog

Comment: Still null after a call to `show()`. I tried several method overloadings,.. no luck. The `listView` is there, but does not have any children before onClick happens.